# Upload Large Video File From Android

Tags: java, android

I can not upload large video to server android?
i try to use this method

```
private void UploadLargeFile(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
try {
    httpclient.start();
    File upload = new File(args[0]);
    File download = new File(args[1]);
    ZeroCopyPost httpost = null;
    try {
        httpost = new ZeroCopyPost(URLTOUploadFile", upload,
                ContentType.create("video/mp4"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ZeroCopyConsumer<File> consumer = null;
    consumer = new ZeroCopyConsumer<File>(download) {

        @Override
        protected File process(final HttpResponse response,
                final File file, final ContentType contentType)
                throws Exception {
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                throw new ClientProtocolException("Upload failed: "
                        + response.getStatusLine());
            }
            return file;
        }

    };
    Future<File> future = httpclient.execute(httpost, consumer, null);
    File result;            
    result = future.get();
    System.out.println("Response file length: " + result.length());
    System.out.println("Shutting down");
} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

}

in the first line of CloseableHttpAsyncClient i got NoSuchFieldFound error
can any one help me?

Comment: Define "server android"

Comment: @shkschneider what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @user3056448 He means, what is the 'server android' you are uploading to.

Comment: sorry, i mean to any server service. but the problem happen while i debug from the first line **NoSuchFieldFound**.note that i put last versions of httpasyncclient-4.1.0.jar & httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar and httpcore-4.3.2.jar